# Extracting all words separated by comma and the conjunction AND after a specific word

Tags: javascript, regex

I am struggling to generate a regex expression that will match each word separated by a comma and the word 'and'.

My input strings will be similar to, `"We will launch new USD-M NFP, MOVR, PLEX and GAS Perpetual Contracts"`
and expected output would match `['NFP','MOVR','PLEX','GAS']`

This is my current regex, `USD-M\s+(\w+((?:\s*,\s*\w+)|(?:\s*and\s*\w+))*)`
Which matches the characters 'USD-M' then any whitespaces before trying to capture the words separated by a comma or 'and'.

Javascript:

```
const input = "We will launch new USD-M NFP, MOVR, PLEX and GAS Margin Contracts";
const regex = /USD-M\s+(\w+((?:\s*,\s*\w+)|(?:\s*and\s*\w+))*)/i;
const output = input.match(regex);
```

However it outputs

```
0:'USD-M NFP, MOVR, PLEX and GAS'
1:'NFP, MOVR, PLEX and GAS'
2:' and GAS'
```

I could use `output[1]` and split by commas & 'and' but surely regex can do what I want.

I appreciate the help!

Edit:

The regex would need to be smart enough so that there being no commas or 'and' only has one match.
For example,

```
Input: "We will launch new USD-M NFP Spot Market"
Output: ['NFP']
```

Comment: "I could use `output[1]` and split by commas & 'and'". That would actually be the preferred and more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Oh right. I'll do it that way then!
Is that because regex doesn't handle my situation? Or it'd end up to complex?

Comment: That does work out nicely! I didn't realize regex can be pasted into split function.

Here's my code;
`let items = output[1].split(/\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/);`

Comment: Regex isn't suited to capturing multiple tokens after one specific pattern. You'll either need two regexes to do it in two steps (like what you suggested already), or use one inefficient regex with a variable-width lookbehind assertion like https://regex101.com/r/4d8inS/1 .

Comment: I see. That's helpful to know.
Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like

```js
const text = 'We will launch new USD-M NFP, MOVR, PLEX and GAS Perpetual Contracts';
console.log(text.match(/\b(?<=\bUSD-M\s+(?:\w+(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+))*)\w+/g));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sk9tsV/1).

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<=\bUSD-M\s+(?:\w+(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+))*)` - a positive lookbehind that requires, to the left of the current location:

  - `\bUSD-M` - a whole word `USD-M` (`\b` is a word boundary and after `M`, there must be a whitespace because...)
  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:\w+(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+))*` - zero or more occurrences of

    - `\w+` - one or more word chars
    - `(?:\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+)` - either a comma enclosed with optional whitespaces, or the word `and` inside one or more whitespaces
- `\w+` - one or more ASCII letters, digits or underscores.